# Mac LWJGL Display no maximization option

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl

On windows, my LWJGL application is able to be maximized, as shown here:

[Maximization allowed http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8428/maximize.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8428/maximize.png)

However, the same application on Mac does not allow you to maximize the display, as shown here:

http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/6653/maximization.png

Is there a line of code that I am missing?

I am able to re-size the window manually to fit the whole screen, however, it would be nice to know if it would be possible to enable the maximize button for the sake of ease.

Answer (score 0):

One try would be to use the nightly builds of LWJGL found here:
https://www.newdawnsoftware.com/jenkins/view/LWJGL/job/LWJGL/
If you aren't using it already. It contains many fixes and additions, maybe even for this problem.

Otherwise the changelog from 2.8.3 just states that it got added and there is no line of code manipulating it. Do you have the same version of LWJGL on your mac?

Comment: I have version 2.8.4 installed.